# \Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib was unexpected at this time. while running apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

when I try to start the Zookeeper server using the command

`.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties`,

I get the below error

> \Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib was unexpected at this time

As I don't have Admin access, I cannot change the `JAVA_HOME`.

Is there any way to resolve this issue, without changing the `JAVA_HOME` in environment variables.

Comment: As a workaround, you might edit the `kafka-run-class.bat` file and setup the path to your Java install.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is working after i set java path and home in the kafka-run-class.bat

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JAVA_HOME temporarily for the terminal session alone as mentioned below. This change doesn't require any administrator privileges.

```
C:\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\bin\windows>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331
```

And now you can happily run zookeeper as below

```
C:\kafka_2.12-3.1.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

JAVA_HOME variable changes will be reverted as soon as you close the window terminal. Hope this helps.